# Loading Message While Function Processes

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am looking for a way to have a pop-up dialog display a loading message while a function executes. I see examples of doing this for a page loading but it is less clear to me how to handle this for a javascript function. I've made several attempts and they fail due my inability to manage the asynchronous nature of this action. Loading the message dialog, then executing the function, then closing the message dialog. For example I can get the message to pop-up fine and have the process running; but trying to add in the close out portion fails. I find that the close dialog portion triggers before the actual function I am trying to process is finished.

I have a loading modal as follows:

```
<loading modal-id="loadingMessage" message="Processing, please wait..."></loading>
```

The function to display the message; which returns a promise:

```
function displayLoadingMessage() {
    var count = 0;
    var defer = $q.defer();

    var stop = $interval(function() {
        var loadingMessage = $('#loadingMessage');

        if (loadingMessage != null && loadingMessage.length > 0) {
            loadingMessage.modal({
                keyboard: false,
                backdrop: 'static'
            });

            $interval.cancel(stop);
            defer.resolve();
        }

        count++;

        if (count > 100) {
            $interval.cancel(stop);  
            defer.resolve();
        }
    }, 100);

    return defer.promise;
};
```

I've tried chaining the calls in an asynchronous fashion as follows:

```
var message = displayLoadingMessage() 
message.then(functionToWaitOn()).then($('#loadingMessage').modal('hide'));
```

The function `functionToWaitOn()` calls other function(s). The basic layout though is:

```
function functionToWaitOn() {
    if(condition == true) {
        secondFunction();
    } else {
        thirdFunction();
    }
}
```

`secondFunction()`/`thirdFunction()` is where the major work is done; they trigger a process on the server side which executes and this is what takes the time.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## EDIT

You need to change fundamentally how you are doing this. `functionToWaitOn()` needs to return a promise, and by the looks of things, so do `secondFunction()` and `thirdFunction()`

I assume somewhere along the way you are calling `$http.get()` or something similar - you need to make that specific function return a promise.

I think you should read up more on how deferred and promises work. See **[this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)** and **[this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)**

```
function functionToWaitOn() {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    if (condition) {
        secondFunction().then(function() { defer.resolve() }
    } else {
        thirdFunction().then(function() { defer.resolve() }
    }
    return defer.promise;
}
```

---

You need to remember that `then()` takes anonymous functions or function pointers as arguments. Your code needs to be:

```
var message = function() {
    return displayLoadingMessage();
}

message().then(function() {
    functionToWaitOn().then(function() {
        $("#loadingMessage").modal('hide');
    }
});
```

Or more simply...

```
displayLoadingMessage().then(function() {
    functionToWaitOn().then(function() {
        $("#loadingMessage").modal('hide');
    }
});
```

Be aware that you might end up in [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/) after this

Comment: I'm trying to get it working this way; I am finding that the function (functionToWaitOn()) is no longer working right. It is complaining that some variables outside the function don't exist (are out of scope now?).

Comment: Well then can you post `functionToWaitOn()` so we can help you

Comment: Currently `functiontoWaitOn()` is a function which calls other functions as needed; I'll try and post something relevant.

Comment: Ok then you've made a fundamental mistake. `functionToWaitOn()` should be the asynchronous one which returns `deferred.promise`, as this is by your definition the function you want to wait for.

Comment: I had though something along these lines at one point; injecting deferred and returning a promise into this function and using a comparable layout above. Any thoughts on where I went wrong?

Comment: Thank you for your assistance; I believe you are correct.

Comment: I am left with the unpleasant realization that I will likely need to provide a promise from every single function triggered by functionToWaitOn(). Including the ones inside functions like thirdFunction().

Comment: I'm certain you can refactor your code to make it more efficient. If you want to post your whole `functionToWaitOn()` and `secondFunction()` and `thirdFunction()` we might be able to help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116110/discussion-between-gedalya-and-nagyben).

Answer (score 1):

Try [Angular-loding-bar](http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/) , it is very simple!

Doucumation - [docs](https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar).

Simple example :

```
angular.module('myApp', ['angular-loading-bar'])
  .config(['cfpLoadingBarProvider', function(cfpLoadingBarProvider) {
    cfpLoadingBarProvider.includeBar = false;
  }])
```